# Невозможно кликнуть с первого раза на ссылку в footer

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Есть сайт на вордпресс.
https://evroflag.by/
После полной его загрузки, невозможно перейти по ссылкам в футере с первого раза. Для этого нужно один раз клинуть по любому месту на сайте, только тогда ссылка становится активной.
Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Учитесь пользоваться инструментами разработчика в браузере.

После загрузки сайта появляется элемент на странице в `body`.

`/html/body/div[9]`

`body > div:nth-child(74)`

И он занимает всю область view порта и первый клик происходит на этот элемент. Я не знаю что это. Dev Tools и дебаг кода вам в помощь)

Но есть предположение. в консоле есть ошибки.

`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function`
`amoforms.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: amo_forms_loaded is not defined`

Возможно если их исправить то все станет работать нормально.

Comment: спасибо. чтобы его скрыть нужно прописать body.div:nth-child(74) {
 display: none !important;
} Верно?

Comment: @Vadzim, так конечно можно сделать) Но это плохое решение. Я бы советовал разобраться в проблеме если есть возможность. Для начала я пофиксил бы ошибки в консоле, может и пропадет эта проблема. 

Просто возможно это элемент какой то библиотеки jQuery а при загрузке почему то `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function` и поэтому не отрабатывает код и не скрывается этот элемент. Может быть такое, что из за ошибки в коде не отрабатывает весь код.

Comment: Кстати, это почему-то не срабатывает. Прописываю это правило но этот див не исчезает body.div:nth-child(74) { display: none !important; }

Comment: Если убрать чат АМО то всё работает замечательно

Comment: @Vadzim, проверьте применяются ли правила. `body.div:nth-child(74) { display: none !important; }`

Comment: Добавил в цсс body.div:nth-child(74) { display: none !important; } но всё равно некликабельная страница с первого раза.....